# MS Access 2007 - Update query won't update

Tags: microsoft-access, query

I have a Access 2007 database that I wish to be able to click a button and update Null values in a table column with the current date when the button is clicked.  For some reason it just won't update.

I created a query qrySubmitUpdate that has the following SQL.

```
 UPDATE tblSubmissions SET tblSubmissions.[fldDateSent] = Date()
 WHERE (((tblSubmissions.[fldDateSent]) Is Null));
```

If I switch the query to view mode, it will show me the appropriate number of rows that need to be updated - all rows are blank and the calendar icon appears next to each row you click on.

The fldDateSent field is set to Date/Time for Data Type.  No default value or validation rule/text.  Input mask is empty and the format is set to Short Date (Doesn't matter if the date is set to short date or empty).

Any idea what I am missing?  Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you run the query manually (run, not just view mode)? Any messages or warnings? By default, you should get a warning that you are about to update XXX number of records, etc.

Comment: No warning or message at all.  I've also tried to type a date where Date() is (example: 12/11/2013)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happened.  It crashed a couple times on me, restarted for about the 5th time and it updated as it's supposed to.